# Reminder Notifications in App (Android or iOS) from Firebase

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, database-trigger

I want to **implement** the **reminder notifications** in my application. 
In the app, the user can add **appointments** by selecting the **date and time**. These appointments are saved in the **Firebase Realtime Database.**

**Database Structure:**

**/appointments/{user_id}**

[image: database structure]

Now I want to add the **notification/reminder** feature so that the users will get the notification before appointment time on that day.

Ideas that I have in my mind:

1. Save each appointment when created/updated in the **Google calendar**. So that the Google calendar will handle the reminders. But the issue is, a user can use the app on more than one device and the Google account can be different on both devices. Another thing is that I want to implement it in a way so that it can work both on iOS and Android.
2. I thought to create a **background service** that will run every day or multiple times in a day to fetch the appointments for that day and the fetched appointments will be saved in Google calendar. This will solve the issue of using the app on multiple devices by a user. But here again, the issue is background service. I believe this background service will not work properly on iOS.
3. Send the notifications from the server as it will solve the issue of Android and iOS platforms.

   a. But here the question is how to check the appointments for each user on the server from Firebase? The userbase is already ~500,000 users.

   b. How to add triggers in the Firebase realtime database so that a user belongs to that appointment can receive the notification.

   c. If I set up a Cron Job in the server that will check the appointments of the user but that Cron Job will take a lot of time, based on the number of users. And that Cron Job needs to be run every minute because the appointment time can be any within an hour.

So I need to know how can I implement this feature? What is the best and appropriate way?
Please let me know your suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to implement this but here's my way to send notification reminders every day at 0000hrs.

Instead of looking through all the users to check the appointments, you create another collection to store the reminders. (I used Firestore but it will work with RTDB). The collection contains documents with userID and reminderDate, the rest of the information about the appointment can be stored separately. 
To notify the users the day before, you just need to set the reminderDate as the actual appointment date - 1 day.

For cronjob, I used [scheduled functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions). It will fire every day at 0000hrs and run a query to get all the documents (if reminderDate == currentDate), store all the userIDs into an array. Next, retrieve all the user's device token and send notification via FCM.

Comment: Yes, I also think to create a separate node for the users based on appointment time. Then the Cron Job will process only those users.

Comment: Another solution could be `Cloud Task` as I read the article https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a and shared my response https://medium.com/@DeepakDroid/how-about-this-idea-3f8e5c05f601